# Flutter - Provider - provide services in main function without MultiProvider widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

In my app root widget I have multiple services provided using `Provider` library - `MultiProvider` widget.

I'm using `flutter_native_splash` with `removeAfter` functionality so I need some services to be initialized inside the `main` function and not inside the root App widget.
Meaning I need to find a way initialize the services and "provide" them without the `MultiProvider` widget and consume them later on down in the tree using the `Consumer` widget.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “injecting” services? There’s no dependency injection in Flutter. You can use the [`value`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/) constructor if you have existing `ChangeNotifier` instances. See *Reusing an existing object instance*

However, you shouldn’t really have business logic in view models, imo. You should have services that are independent, and use a library like [GetIt](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to manage their instance lifetimes.

Comment: updated the post - agree but this is how the flutter_native_splash works.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `Signleton` class and use it anywhere in app something like this,

```
Class Example{
 Example._();
 static final Example instance = Example._();
 Future<void> init () async {
 //initialise whatever you want
 }
}
```

and use it in you main like this,

```
 void main()async{
  await Example.instance.init();
 }
```